# Post a timestamp data when Logout event occurred in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, logout

Below code is `Login Event Listener` when login event occurred.

I made also `Logout Event Listener` as same design with Login one.

It works, but it just making another row in same table.

Then how could I make `Logout` data to same row that login data posted in table?
Is it possible to post a data to `deleted_at` of login data saved row?

Thanks:)

**LogSuccessfulLogin.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\LoginHistory;

class LogSuccessfulLogin
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */

    public function handle(Login $event)
    {

        LoginHistory::create([
            'user_name' => $event->user->name,
            'last_login_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'last_login_ip' => $this->request->ip(),
        ]);

        $user = $event->user;
        $user->last_login_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->last_login_ip = $this->request->ip();
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

**LogSuccessfulLogout.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\LogoutHistory;
use App\LoginHistory;
use \Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTime;

class LogSuccessfulLogout
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Logout $event)
    {   
    $log = LoginHistory::where('user_name', $event->user->name)->first();

        if($log) 
        {
            //logout timestamp store.
            $log->last_logout_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $log->save();

            //calculate time_worked 
            $strStart = Carbon::now(); 
            $strEnd   = $log->last_login_at;      
            $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
            $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd);      
            $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd); 
            // print $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S"); 
            // dd($dteDiff);
            $log->time_worked = $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");
            $log->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what are logout data in your case in the LoginHistory table ?

Comment: @Maraboc, Hi ;) in the case, just want to post logout timestamp data to same row of login data stored.

Comment: @Magnetic, instead of inserting , use updating the existing record using the logout timestamp. You can update the record on the bases of user_id or user_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it's simple find the LogoutHistory with user id then update it :

```
public function handle(Logout $event)
{
   $log = LogoutHistory::where('user_name', $event->user->name)
                  ->latest('last_login_at')
                  ->first();

    if($log) {
        $log->last_logout_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $log->save();
    }
}
```

PS : assuming that the user_name is unique in the user table

Comment: Fantastic!! It works!! you are always save my life :)

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Comment: I had little error, when logged out, then just recently row data up to date and another generated just before row had not stored last_logged_at data,  three and more were same action. :(

Comment: Ok i see, it's because you insert a new row for each log in in your application? i think you can just update `last_login_at` for the same record of the user if it exists is that ok with your logic ?

Comment: Or you want a history for all your logging operations ==> user can see i was logging last week for 30min, something like that ?

Comment: I wish to calculate worked time from each sessions. so after then, should use to calculate montly and over.  ^.^ thanks.

Comment: Check the update answer => just add ->latest('last_login_at')  :)

Comment: you do not need more compliments :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [soft delete](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting) for adding `deleted_at` column.

then you can query like this

```
$log = LogoutHistory::where('user_name', $event->user->name)->delete();
```

this will add timestamp in `deleted_at` column.

Comment: @Pyramid, Thank you for answer, but it deleted already stored login row also.:(

Comment: you need to use softdelete first see the docs for how to use softdeletes then try my code it will not delete any row

Comment: @Pyramid, Thank you. It also include softDeletes(), your code was worked well. By the way, upper Maraboc's code is doing post a data to row of login data stored. and your code is need 2 tables( LogoutHistory and LoginHistory) as my first idea. Have a nice day :)